# Why form submit keep defaulting to a particular POST action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Imagine a typical Rails 4.2 application with a resource called location. Within the LocationsController, we have the usual actions.

The new view and the edit view both utilize a shared partial called _location_form.html.erb. I want to recycle that same partial view for two additional custom actions, clone and clone_create. The clone (GET) action has the same code body as the edit action. The clone_create (POST) action has the same code body as the create action.

The ultimate goal is to add a 'Clone' button on show.html.erb, which leads to clone.html.erb that has a particular location's data already pre-populated on the shared partial. The user modifies the form field values accordingly, clicks submit and the clone_create action is triggered saving that location to the database. Essentially, "cloning" is akin to editing a location then creating a new location upon form submit.

```
# new.html.erb
<h1>New Location</h1>
<%= render :partial => 'admin/shared/location_form', :locals => { :url => admin_data_provider_location_index_path } %>

# edit.html.erb
<h1>Edit Location</h1>
<%= render :partial => 'admin/shared/location_form', :locals => { :url => admin_data_provider_location_path(@location) } %>

# clone.html.erb
<h1>Clone Location</h1>
<%= render :partial => 'admin/shared/location_form', :locals => { :url => clone_create_admin_data_provider_location_index_path } %>

# _location_form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @location], :url => url, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    .................
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn' %>
<% end %>


# locations_controller.rb
class Admin::DataProvider::LocationsController < AdminController
    ................
    def new
        @location = Location.new
        ...........
    end

    def create
        # Creates a location and saves it to the database.
        ...........
        render :new
    end

    def edit
        @location = Location.find(params[:id])
        ...........
    end

    def update
        @location = Location.find(params[:id])
        # Saves edited location field values back to same location in the database.
        ...........
        render :edit
    end

    def clone
        # Same code body as edit.
    end

    def clone_create
        # Same code body as create.
    end
    ..................
end


# routes.rb
namespace :admin do
    ..........
    namespace :data_provider do
        resources :location, :controller => :locations, :exception => [:destroy] do
            get 'clone', :on => member
            post 'clone_create', :on => :collection
            .............


# rake routes | grep location
clone_admin_data_provider_location GET /admin/data_provider/location/:id/clone(.:format) admin/data_provider/locations#clone

clone_create_admin_data_provider_location_index POST /admin/data_provider/location/clone_create(.:format) admin/data_provider/locations#clone_create

edit_admin_data_provider_location GET /admin/data_provider/location/:id/edit(.:format) admin/data_provider/locations#edit

admin_data_provider_location PATCH PUT /admin/data_provider/location/:id(.:format) admin/data_provider/locations#update

new_admin_data_provider_location GET /admin/data_provider/location/new(.:format) admin/data_provider/locations#new

admin_data_provider_location_index POST /admin/data_provider/location(.:format) admin/data_provider/locations#create
```

The clone action behaves fine. For example, hitting the url /location/123/clone brings up the shared partial form filled with data exactly like hitting /location/123/edit. Great.

The issue comes when the clone form is submitted. The form POST request absolutely refuses to execute the clone_create action. The form posts to update every single time, no matter how I modify clone.html.erb or

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @location], :url => url, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

This is some high level Rails magic happening here where Rails FORCES posting to a specific action regardless of what the developer code wants.

1) Why does the clone form keep posting to update when I obviously want it to post to clone_create?

2) How do I update the current code or what additional code do I have to write to ensure the clone form posts to clone_create?

Any reference links or resources to better help with my understanding would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `url` in the `form`?

Comment: I'm assuming it's `clone_create_admin_data_provider_location_index_path` which is passed into the partial from clone.html.erb. Here's the thing tough, no matter how I modify `url` in `form`, it's still posting to update. I've tried to replace it with `:clone_create`, `{action: 'clone_create'}`, `{controller: 'location', action: 'clone_create'}`, `{:action => :clone_create}`..... etc. Every combination of `clone_create` or `create`. Nothing matters as the form still defaults to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that you need a specific clone_create method.

```
def clone
  @location = Location.find(params[:id]).dup
  render :new
end
```

Then you have (effectively) a new record which happens to have the same values as the old record, and can be processed by the standard `create` method.

Note that as long as you're showing an existing record, submit will always take you to the update action.